(Flutter) HTTP Request not responding for newest android devices
I'm using Flutter to create a cross platform app and this error happened for only newest Android Devices such as Galaxy S23 Ultra and Galaxy S24+.
Future<int> register(
    String name, 
    String password, 
    String phoneNo, 
    String birthday, 
    String gender
    ) async {
      var pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      var token = pref.getString(SharedPreferencesKeys.fcmToken) ?? '';
      Map data = {
        'username': name,
        'userbirth': birthday,
        'gender': gender,
        'phoneno': phoneNo,
        'password': password,
        'fcm': token,
      };
      var url = Uri.parse(Url.getSignupUrl());
      var body = json.encode(data);
      try {
        var response = await http.post(
          url,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: body,
        ).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 10));
        
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          Map<String, dynamic> decodedJson = json.decode(response.body); // for future use
          String accessToken = decodedJson['result']['tokens']['accessToken']['accessToken'];
          int accessTokenTimeout = decodedJson['result']['tokens']['accessToken']['timeout'];
          String refreshToken = decodedJson['result']['tokens']['refreshToken']['refreshToken'];
          int refreshTokenTimeout = decodedJson['result']['tokens']['refreshToken']['timeout'];
          String userId = decodedJson['result']['userId'];
          const storage = FlutterSecureStorage(
              aOptions: AndroidOptions(
                encryptedSharedPreferences: true,
              )
            );
          print('register: $userId, $name, $phoneNo, $birthday, $sex');
          storage.write(key: SecureStorageKeys.userId, value: userId);
          storage.write(key: SecureStorageKeys.name, value: name);
          storage.write(key: SecureStorageKeys.phoneNo, value: phoneNo);
          storage.write(key: SecureStorageKeys.birthday, value: birthday);
          storage.write(key: SecureStorageKeys.sex, value: sex);
          await pref.setString(SharedPreferencesKeys.accessToken, accessToken); 
          await pref.setString(SharedPreferencesKeys.refreshToken, refreshToken);
          await pref.setInt(SharedPreferencesKeys.accessTokenTimeout, accessTokenTimeout);
          await pref.setInt(SharedPreferencesKeys.refreshTokenTimeout, refreshTokenTimeout);
          return(response.statusCode);
        } else {
          return(-1);
        }
      } catch (e) {
          return(-1);
      }
  }

Above is the code that I'm getting stuck at. The colleague of mine working for the backend says that he's not catching any requests. Clearly should be client's mistake.
Also the API Endpoint is http://WW.XXX.YYY.ZZZ:3000/my/route
I thought the code was working because it worked fine for any iOS Devices and some older version of Android devices (Galaxy Tab A7 Lite and Android Emulators from Android Studio - they use Android 14)
I also added the config file at main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">WW.XXX.YYY.ZZZ</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>


and this is my Android Manifest under main
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="mylabel"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:extractNativeLibs="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:showWhenLocked="true"
            android:turnScreenOn="true"
            >
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".VerificationActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        />
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />


            <receiver
                android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver"
                android:exported="false" />
            <receiver
                android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
                android:exported="false" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                    <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
    <!-- Tell Google Play Store that your app uses Bluetooth LE
     Set android:required="true" if bluetooth is necessary -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false" />

    <!-- New Bluetooth permissions in Android 12
    https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/bluetooth-permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- legacy for Android 9 or lower -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
</manifest>


Flutter Doctor if anyone is interested
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.0, on macOS 14.2 23C64 darwin-arm64, locale ko-KR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.94.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.91.1)
[✓] Network resources

Does anyone have an idea where I am getting it wrong?

Are you seeing the request actually fire? What is the response? Any logs?

@tomerpacific That was the thing, I couldn't confirm whether if the request was actually firing. There weren't any logs either, it seemed that the debugger pointer just vanish after 'await http.post' and then after 10 seconds the timeout is called.

you can use dev tools to see rest api activity in network tab.

I found out why. Our service was hosted on the isolated network only accessible by office wifi.
The tester was using the 5G network when he tried to make request which obviously failed. The reason why other older test devices were working was that they can only use wifi internet as they were not wired to any carrier services.
It wasn't neither of front-end or back-end problem and one of the wierdest error I got haha.
